# Can I add a WCF service to an existing project

Tags: wcf

Looking at an earlier 3.5 based solution, there is an WCF service within the same web project.  I thought WCF services generally got their own project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually separate my WCF projects out for maintenance purposes, but they can be within a web project. It is basically the same thing as the old ASMX [WebMethod] process. In fact, any method in a code-behind of a web form can be turned into a web service method by decorating the method accordingly.